# Module has no exported member 'AWS'

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, es6-module-loader

Can someone help me understand how different the namespace and module is?

AWS.d.ts

```
declare module AWS {
  ...
  ...
}
export = AWS
```

helper.d.ts

```
export declare namespace Helpers{
  ...
  ...
}
```

app.component.d.ts

```
import {Helpers} from 'mystartup_commons'; //<= works fine
import {AWS} from 'aws-sdk';
```

Error:

> ERROR in
>   /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/myproj/src/app/app.component.ts
>   (1,9): Module '"/Users/is
>   handutta2007/Documents/Projects/myproj/node_modules/aws-sdk/typings/AWS"'
>   has no exported member 'AWS'.)

Answer (score 13):

adding a reference path to node's definition file and using `* as` did the trick

app.component.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"/>
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

Comment: The downside to this is that it might import all of the AWS library and defeat tree shaking.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the reason that the aws-sdk has no default export is because they want developers to only import the packages they need. e.g.

`import { s3 } from 'aws-sdk';`

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo: `modeule` instead of `module`
2. Seems like you can't export whole module. See here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html
   https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

Answer (score -1):

Issue was resolve on [Github: node_modules/aws-sdk/index has no default export #2654](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2654)

Import module you want to use instead of `AWS` from  `aws-sdk`

Javascript sample:

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
let s3 = new aws.S3();
```

Typescript:

```
import { config, S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
import {
  Buckets,
  GetObjectOutput,
  ListBucketsOutput,
  PutObjectRequest 
} from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';
```

Comment: Some elaboration would be really appreciated.